# Android material button with spinning icon

Tags: android, materialbutton

Is it possible to have a spinning icon (like progressbar) as the material button icon?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a progress bar itself and add onclick event listener so that it can behave like a button
add `onClick="whenProgressBarIsClicked()"` to your XML
and below statement to your Java code

add

```
public void whenProgressBarIsClicked(){ 
//Do some wonderful stuff here
}
```

If you use Kotlin, you can replace the above code with your Kotlin code.

Comment: Thanks, but I need a button with spinning icon

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can implement on Button

I used it in Material FloatingButton.

Make this file **SlideUp__Animation.xml** in ***res/anim/***  folder

```
   <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

          <translate
            android:duration="700"
            android:fromYDelta="90%"
            android:toYDelta="0"
    
           />
   </set>
```

Apply this in the main class's floating button.

```
fButton.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.slideup__animation));
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work on the icon itself, it works on the button.
I want to have animation on the icon

Comment: Can you put here your code and bugs which you get in implementation.

Comment: you just can't do button.icon.startAnimation, it's not supported

Comment: if I do it on the button, it works, but I don't want the animation on the button, but only on the icon

Comment: Ok i understand. I 'll find the Solution.